# Angular2 AOT Testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, angular, angular2-aot

I currently started using NGC to make my libraries AOT ready, none-the-less I noticed that sometimes some errors are only visible upon consuming the library rather than at compilation level during NGC. (Not these errors are ngc errors which cannot be solved with a Unit Test)

Thus, I'd like to test somehow, to avoid shipping a library with issues when consuming the library.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Dou you have an example?

Comment: i am more looking of proper workflow to test. Ie: some people suggest to use a starter project and just integrate your library with it and test manually, which in reality is not practical. Thus the reason I created the post.

Comment: here http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/ or here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: Thanks for the links although they are a bit out of scope of my question as those are on creating the AOT not on how to test the generated AOT library itself.

Comment: That's a very new topic, there is currently no cook-receipt to my mind,..